# How to get the paypal payment/items/client info on the website?

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I have a small website used to sell mods for a game. At the moment, I use PayPal's shoping cart and I would like to make a "success.php" page, which the user is redirected to after the payment has been successfully done. I would like to know how can I get the names of the items in a table, something like:

"You have successfully bought the following item(s):

- Item1
- Item2 "

And also the total payment amount.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the paypal api then set the variable

`item_name=".urlencode($your_item_names)`

And you will get the response back the same whether or failure then retrieve it like

`$_POST['item_name']`.

Comment: The problem is I don't really know what you are talking about... What paypal api you are saying about? And what variable?

Comment: you are using `paypal` gateway to implement the payment..right? you are using API by some PHP code of course..

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit more complicated than just receiving parameters.

use this script: [GitHub Paypal](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php)

change email and test with: [Paypal Developer Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator)